# Can I install Kernel 2.6.22 on Trusty 14.04 Lubuntu without compiling?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, lubuntu, macbook-pro

I am trying to install an older kernel to  install on my Macbook Pro so that suspend works.

Is this possible without having to compile everything?

To my understanding I would need just download

```
linux-image-2.6.2x --i386.deb
linux-headers-2.6.2x --i386.deb
linux-headers-2.6.2x_  --all.deb
```

Installing them via `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` and then rebooting and choosing this kernel at boot startup options.

Is this somehow correct?

Comment: Kernel 2.6.22 is extremely outdated and has many severe security vulnerabilities. You should really try to find a way to make suspend work with a modern kernel rather than going back to such an ancient one.

Comment: thanks, i found out that suspend actually works with the newer kernel, only my lid has some problem seems. so i consider this closed.

Comment: well, actually, i was wrong, the suspend only works if i was not logged on yet; after logging in, suspend doessn't work anymore.
can someone please show me where to download .debs of older kernels for ubuntu?

Comment: If it works when you're not logged in, it's almost certainly not the kernel. The kernel doesn't even have a concept of whether users are logged in.